# Cloud Database for Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, cloud

I've programmed in Objective-C for some time and used Parse as a back end. I was wondering if there is a backend to incorporate with a swift application as I build a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Parse as your backend. They have updated their documentation and added the Swift equivalent of their example-codes etc.

[Check this as example](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS) Just click on the <kbd>Swift</kbd> button on the bottom right side of a code-snippet and you will see the Swift-code.

Also you can use their Parse API in Swift too, without any problems. Just import the SDK into your project.